# Error Running Jython Script from WSADMIN

Tags: websphere, jython, wsadmin

I am running a Jython script from `wsadmin`. This is the portion where its throwing an error.

**SCRIPT**:

```
..
..
objNameString = AdminControl.completeObjectName('WebSphere:type=Server,*') 
NODE_NAME=AdminControl.getAttribute(objNameString, 'nodeName') 
CELL_NAME=AdminControl.getCell()
SERVER_NAME= "MyAppServer"
..
..
# Start Web application
print "Starting Web Application..."
appManager = AdminControl.queryNames('cell='+ CELL_NAME +',node='+ NODE_NAME +',type=ApplicationManager,process='+ SERVER_NAME +',*')
print appManager
AdminControl.invoke(appManager, 'startApplication', 'AppName')
print "Web Application Started..."
```

**ERROR**:

```
Starting Web Application...
WASX7017E: Exception received while running file "/scratch/py/CreateWPSDomain.py"; exception information: com.ibm.ws.scripting.ScriptingException: WASX7025E: Error found in String ""; cannot create ObjectName.
```

Anything wrong with the way I have concatenated ? Coz the error like this seems to come when values are empty or not registered properly.

**Update**: Is there any sample jython scripts which I can reference. My req: 1. Creates a server > 2. Install the war file > 3. Creates Datasources > 4. Starts the Server > 5. Starts the Application.

Comment: print out your parameters before you call queryNames and make sure you are getting the right values.

Comment: you can also add -debug to the commandline

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please make sure that your server is started, I think when you are calling the command... the Server is not started yet. Give a delay or keep a check whether the server is up ...then issue the command

Comment: This seems like a generic answer but check the app server is up not just the node+cluster is up.

Answer (score 2):

The error message says that ObjectName cannot be created from empty string. That empty string was returned from `queryNames`.

Try this:

```py
appManager = AdminControl.queryNames('WebSphere:cell='+ CELL_NAME +',node='+ NODE_NAME +',type=ApplicationManager,process='+ SERVER_NAME +',*')
```

BTW: with WDR library (http://wdr.github.io/WDR/) your script would be much simpler. With some other improvements it could look as follows:

```py
SERVER_NAME= "MyAppServer"

# Start Web application
print "Starting Web Application..."
appManager = getMBean1(process = SERVER_NAME, type = 'ApplicationManager')
print appManager
appManager.startApplication('AppName')
print "Web Application Started..."
```

**Disclosure:** I'm one of key WDR contributors.

Comment: It didn't work... Same error I am getting. 
Anything wrong with the way I have concatenated ? Coz the error like this seems to come when values are empty or not registered properly.

Comment: Are you using WAS ND? In that case, the `completeObjectName` may return a wrong server. If your application was deployed to cluster, you may have to invoke `startApplication` for each cluster member. Your script may only work with WAS Base (non-ND). If your server name is unique, you may skip cell= and node= in queryNames: `AdminControl.queryNames('WebSphere:type=ApplicationManager,process='+ SERVER_NAME +',*')`

Answer (score 0):

The error is thrown at this line:

`AdminControl.invoke(appManager, 'startApplication', 'AppName')`

Check your `appManager` variable, and make sure it is not empty. 
 `AdminControl.queryNames(..)` will return an empty string if a match is not found.

`AdminControl.invoke(..)` requires an MBean descriptor (object name) string to be passed as the first argument, and the error you are receiving is `wsadmin` telling you that an MBean cannot be resolved with what it received.  The `WASX7025E: Error found in String ""` section of the error is telling you that it received an empty string (`"")` for the MBean descriptor.

Answer (score 0):

/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/Dmgr01/bin>./wsadmin.sh -conntype NONE

WASX7357I: By request, this scripting client is not connected to any server process. Certain configuration and application operations will be available in local mode.

WASX7029I: For help, enter: "$Help help"
wsadmin>wsadmin>wsadmin>securityon wsadmin IWWWWW
WASX7015E: Exception running command: "securityon wsadmin IWWWWW"; exception information:
com.ibm.ws.scripting.ScriptingException: AdminControl service not available

wsadmin>securityoff
LOCAL OS security is off now but you need to restart server1 to make it affected.

wsadmin>

Comment: How does this relate to the question? Is that code in any way?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the server was up and I was still getting this error. 
The issue is that I wasn't connecting to any server because I was including -conntype NONE when running the script via wsadmin. 
The fix is to avoid -conntype NONE to be able to run AdminControl commands 
**/opt/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/default/bin/wsadmin.sh <strike>-conntype NONE</strike> -user  -password  -f**